# Smoothly choosing SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, svd

Let $X$ be a connected open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:X\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ be smooth. Under what conditions can we smoothly choose a singular value decomposition, i.e. find smooth maps $U,V:X\rightarrow U(2)$ and $\Sigma$ from $X$ to the 2x2 diagonal matrices with real, positive entries such that $f(x)=U(x)\Sigma(x)\bar{V}(x)^T$.

How should one go about attempting such a question?

Comment: The singular values must have multiplicity one. Or, more generally.  the multiplicities must remain constant.